# Symfony 2.1 app.session.flashbag.get('something') returns empty value

Tags: php, session, symfony

I have a trouble with using `app.session.flashbag.get('notice')`.

In the controller I make

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entity = $em->getRepository('SomeBundle:SomeEntity')->find($id);

    $editForm = $this->createForm(new SomeEntityType(), $entity);
    $editForm->bind($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

        $flash = $this->get('translator')->trans('Some Entity was successfully updated');
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', $flash);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some_entity_edit', array('id' => $id)));

    }
```

In editAction I'm getting information from the session:

```
public function editAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $flashes = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->get('notice', array());

    //...
    //...

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'flashes' => $flashes
    );
}
```

And  i'm trying in the TWIG get information from the session :

```
TWIG: {% for flashMessage in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}{{ flashMessage }}{% endfor %}

PHP: {% for flashMessage2 in flashes %}{{ flashMessage2 }}{% endfor %}
```

The app.session.flashbag.get('notice') is empty, the flashes has a value.

Do you have any ideas, why I can't get data from the app.session.flashbag.get('notice')?

Comment: Why don't you use `setFlash()` and `getFlash()`?

Comment: Because it's not Symfony 2.0, this is Symfony 2.1 (look at http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its normal behavior. You access flash in controller first, so it is returned and unset then. When you access it again then key does not exists in flashbag that way is empty.

See [FlashBag::get](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Flash/FlashBag.php#L95) at github

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know about it. But the trouble was, before I added the code to retrieve information from the session in PHP controller. It worked with Symfony 2.1.1, but after updating Symfony to 2.1.2 flashes disappeared

Comment: @yashchar that strange indeed IRC this behvaior is quite old (for sure is in all 2.1.x versions).

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to handle (add/display) **Symfony flash messages** with [FlashAlertBundle](https://github.com/rasanga/FlashAlertBundle), it is standalone Symfony2 bundle implemented with pure JavaScript, so you don't have to worry about using JS libraries.

You just need the following code to render flash messages on your twig template:

```
{{ render_flash_alerts() }}
```

**Available through**
https://github.com/rasanga/FlashAlertBundle
https://packagist.org/packages/ras/flash-alert-bundle