# Symfony2 session-flash with if clause in twig isn't working

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I try to react on a setted session-flash but get always the else-path

Symfony 2.1.3

Controller:

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->set('contactActionNoticeError', 'Message not sent');
```

View (tried "old" and new style) But I get **bla2**

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.has("contactActionNoticeError") or app.session.hasFlash("contactActionNoticeError") %}
    bla1
{% else %}
    bla2
{% endif %}
```

when showing all flashes with this:

```
{% for label, flashes in app.session.flashbag.all %}
    {% for flash in flashes %}
        {{ label }} - {{ flash }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I get this:

```
contactActionNoticeError - Message not sent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the flashbag content then see if it's empty or not:

```
{% set contactActionNoticeError = app.session.flashbag.get("contactActionNoticeError") %}

{% if (contactActionNoticeError is not empty) %}
    bla1
{% else %}
    bla2
{% endif %}
```

You can still display the errors (code taken from the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/controller.html#flash-messages)):

```
{% for flashMessage in contactActionNoticeError %}
    <div>
        {{ flashMessage }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I edited your answer to `set contactActionNoticeError`. So this works. But there is still the question why `.has` or `.hasFlash` isn't working

Comment: The [flashbag is empty once you accessed it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724771/symfony-2-1-app-session-flashbag-getsomething-returns-empty-value/12732587#12732587). Do you access only once to the flashbag?

Comment: I access flashbag later but how you see I'm able to access the flashbar more than once. I changed my code to read out the flashbags at start and so it works

Answer (score 2):

I know an old question but, I'd like to add an answer as there is a better way of doing things. As noted above, the default behaviour is to unset the flashbag once accessed (which is not so convenient if wanting to check first)

```
// Instead of 
{% if app.session.flashBag.get('success') is not empty %}
// Use this instead
{% if app.session.flashBag.peek('success') is not empty %}
```

Source for this information: [Github FlashBag](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Flash/FlashBag.php#L79)

Answer (score 0):

This is a long shot at best but are you maybe using `FOSUserBundle`?

I had similar problem few months ago where `FOSUserBundle` pulled every flash message out of  session just to display them at login page.

Also, since you have mentioned that you're using `2.1.3`, session management is done a bit differently from `2.0.x`:

http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: No I'm not using FOSUserBundle. And How I said: By iterating thru the flashes with `app.session.flashbag.all` I can see my message.