# Symfony test if there are flashmessages

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a container for all of my flashmessages that is outside of the FOR statement which gets displayed even if there are no flash messages available.

Code below does its job perfectly, i just want to prevent the container from being displayed if there are no flashes to display. I'm trying to find a way to make a Twig IF to test it.

```
<div class="flashMsgContainer">
    {% for flash_message in app.session.flashBag.get('success') %}
        {# more code #}
    {% endfor %}

    {% for flash_message in app.session.flashBag.get('warning') %}
        {# more code #}
    {% endfor %}

    {# more code #}

</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Symfony2 session-flash with if clause in twig isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692996/symfony2-session-flash-with-if-clause-in-twig-isnt-working)

Comment: I don't think this answer about Symfony2 was uptodate :)

Answer (score -1):

You can test flashes length without clear it with this code :

```
{% if app.session.flashbag.peekAll()|length > 0  %}
```